# change / update entity with a different subclass

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a table `Product`, depending on the value of the field `Type` (values: 0,1 or 2) I want to (automatically) instantiate a different subclass with the EntityFramework 6.

So in the designer (VS 2013, EF6) I made my desired mapping + subclasses. One field, the `AdditionalPrice`, is only available in one of the subclasses. This works flawlessly. I can insert, delete and even update Products, no matter, what subclass they are.

I update like this: `context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(modified);` where `original`, is the unchanged entity-object, and `modified` is a new object with different values.

Now the problem I have is: When my `modified`object is not the same subclass anymore (obviously it still has the same baseclass, let's say it was `SpecialProductB` and changed to `SpecialProductA`) it won't update the `AdditionalPrice` field and also won't change the value of the field `type`, which I defined for the mapping.

How can I accomplish that it will update all fields? I mean it's quite obvious for me that it won't work with the `SetValues`methods, the method itself says it will just discard fields, which the `original` field doesn't have.

[image: Mapping and DB-Table]
(Picture in "big": https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYGYK.png)

Comment: You can't change the type of a class other than creating a new class and copying values to it. Even if you could change `type` a `SpecialProductB` object wouldn't change into a `SpecialProductA` object. (That's why the discriminator, `type`, is not exposed in the model). Also, if you'd change a `B` int `A`, how could `AdditionalPrice` be updated? There's no source value for it. If you want to change a type you can only go through the back door, e.g. change the type by raw SQL and _then_ materialize the object.

Comment: With a "converter" I convert the object of these classes to DTOs which are passed via a service (the DTO is not subclassed and is only a "Product" with an Enum for "ProductType"). When I convert this "changed" DTOs back I just build new classes - and that's how the change from Class A to Class B happens (basically it's a new class and not a change, thats also why I update my original object, with the new object).... but I don't think that changes much for your answer? Or is there any  way I can just replace ALL data of my class a with the one of class B in the database? (without raw sql)

Comment: Ah OK. No you can't. But if you create a B from values of A (mediated by a DTO) it should be a B with the discriminator value of a B. But you must make sure that the new B has the same primary key as the original A (and set its state as Modified). I'm not sure though if EF is going to like that.

Comment: And I have no idea how to this ;) But thanks anyway :)